# Pass element ID into js function when the element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a tab style view, as seen here: http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Tabs-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/

My issue is that I have forms on each of these tabs, and outside of the tabs on the page I have a button which resets all the forms and submits, but I want one that resets the form on the current top tab.

So I think the best way would be too have it so when the tab is clicked that a value is sent to the tab form reset script so it knows which form to reset if its clicked.

The forms have ids of "tabf1", "tabf2" etc, so I just need the tab click to send the tab number.

What I've tried:

```
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li onclick="setTabNo(this)" id="1"  class="active">    
    <a href="#tab1">Basic</a></li>

    <li onclick="setTabNo(this)" id="2" ><a href="#tab2">Earnings</a></li>

    <li onclick="setTabNo(this)" id="3" ><a href="#tab3">Deductions</a></li>

    <li onclick="setTabNo(this)" id="4" ><a href="#tab4">Taxes</a></li>
</ul>


function resetAll() {
    document.getElementById("tabf1").reset();
    document.getElementById("tabf2").reset();
    document.getElementById("tabf3").reset();
    document.getElementById("tabf4").reset();
}

var tabNo;
function setTabNo() {
    var tabNo = this.id;
}

function resetTab() {
    document.getElementById("tabf"+tabNo).reset();
}
```

I've tried with the on click and id as part of the  aswell, this based on an answer below, but still doesn't work for me.

The variable is being called in another function, but should be fine as I define it first outside of both.

Solved:

It isn't getting the id sadly, but I just put the id value in the function brackets at the onlick.

So:

```
onclick="setTabNo('2')"
```

Then:

```
function setTabNo(idv) {
    tabNo = idv;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the ID at all, it's already available as a property of the clicked element:

```
function setTab2(element) {
    var id = element.id;
    ...
 }
```

and then change the `onclick` attribute to `onclick="setTab2(this)"`.  The latter ensures that the click handler is passed a reference to the clicked element.

Note that it would be preferable not to use inline event handlers at all:

```
$('#2').on('click', setTab2);
```

NB: numeric IDs are only permitted in HTML5, and are *not* permitted in CSS3.

Comment: I tried the first way and it doesn't work, I've updated my question with it, perhaps there is an error.

Comment: you've got two `tabNo` variables - the outer (global) one is being hidden by the local one inside `setTabNo`.

Comment: p.s. please don't modify your questions like that - *add* the detail, don't replace it.  Adding it causes context to get lost, making the answers you've received make less sense to future readers.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, ok removed the second "var" declaration, stuff doesn't work, if I make the internal tabNo simply equal a number it works, so it is firing, and being seen within the other function, it just isn't getting the id

Comment: so what happens if you put `alert(this.id)` inside that function?

Comment: Says "undefined" when I click the tab.

Comment: what browser?  Maybe it doesn't support numeric-only IDs.

Comment: Chrome, but I've tried with none numeric id values aswell.

Comment: d'oh!  I see the problem...  It's fixed now.  I forgot that I was _passing_ `this` as a parameter, and not using it as the function context.  See http://jsfiddle.net/ug8d0p8h/1/

Comment: oooh yeah, I've not done this for over a year, and seeing that brought it all flooding back, been googling this, and nowhere has done that, thanks :)

Comment: @bob this is why inline event handlers are a bad idea.  Using JS to register them ensures that `this` works properly, and correctly separates code from markup.  Oh, and the other problem with inline handlers is that they can only invoke functions that are in the global scope.